# Populate JavaScript Array from JSON Format

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

Hi I have JSON data that looks like this:

```
[
  {"Mean of Arrivals for each hour":
     {"03-04":-35.62,"04-05":-3.62,"05-06":-3.7}
  }
]
```

I want to push it to an array, and have the array look like this:

```
[
{x: 03-04 y: -35.62},
{x: 04-05, y: -3.62},
{x: 05-06, y: -3.7}
]
```

Right now, it looks like the array below, and I don't know how to format it to look like above. Below is also the code I am using to populate the array. Would love some help on how to format the array.

```
[
x: {03-04: -35.62, 04-05: -3.62, 05-06: -3.7},
y: {03-04: -35.62, 04-05: -3.62, 05-06: -3.7}
]
```

```
var dataPoints = []; // final array with data

var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
chartData.addColumn('string', 'Stunde');
chartData.addColumn('number', 'Ankunft');

function addData(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        dataPoints.push({
          x: data[i]["Mean of Arrivals for each hour"],
          y: data[i]["Mean of Arrivals for each hour"]
         });
    }

    dataPoints.forEach(function (row) {
        chartData.addRow([row.x, row.y]);
    });

    console.log(dataPoints);
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('plot3'));
    chart.draw(chartData, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};

$.getJSON(url, addData);
```

Comment: what if there are more objects in the `data` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to loop through the properties, construct the JSON and push to the array:

```js
const data = [
  {"Mean of Arrivals for each hour":
     {"03-04":-35.62,"04-05":-3.62,"05-06":-3.7}
  }
]
const result = [], r = data[0]["Mean of Arrivals for each hour"];

for(const key in r) result.push({x: key, y: r[key]})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hi thanks it works, however when i push the x-values and y-values into the data table for the chart, it doesnt create a chart... any idea why? i am reusing code from another chart that works in the same fashion with the same array structure, so i am a little lost

Comment: @luthienaerendell No problem. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Google Charts. I would recommend asking another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

This flattens everything out into a single array of data and then processes the objects through map(). It will accommodate any number of arrays inside the object, and any number of sets of coordinates inside those arrays.

```js
let obj = [
  {"Mean of Arrivals for each hour":
     {"03-04":-35.62,"04-05":-3.62,"05-06":-3.7}
  }
]

let result = obj.map(Object.values).flat().map(Object.entries).flat().map(e => ({x:e[0], y:e[1]}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the Object.entries() of the sub objects in the array and create a new object for each of the entries

```js
const data = [
  {"Mean of Arrivals for each hour":
     {"03-04":-35.62,"04-05":-3.62,"05-06":-3.7}
  }
]

const key = "Mean of Arrivals for each hour",
      res = [];

data.forEach(o => Object.entries(o[key]).forEach(([x, y]) => res.push({x, y})))

console.log(res)
```